# WPF draggable list for desktop

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, gridview, draggable

ListView and GridView from the Windows.UI.Xaml.Control namespace apparently (I haven't used them) provide draggable functionality; ie, where you can re-order items in a list by dragging items with the mouse.  However, ListView and GridView are available only for Windows Runtime.

I need that sort of functionality for Windows Desktop (my app needs to run on Windows 7) and have searched extensively without success in trying to find controls with that functionality.

So my question is simply, are there controls for Windows Desktop with that functionality?  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the ReorderListBox from the [bag-of-tricks (BOT) library.](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot) which comes with drag-and-drop functionality out of the box. The BOT is a pretty cool package altogether with some very useful controls.

The ReorderListBox in there is a subclass of the ListBox in the System.Windows.Controls namespace and works with WPF and Silverlight.